# Checkbox to toggle Application Insights Diagnostics on a Worker Role in VS2015 not toggling

Tags: visual-studio, azure-worker-roles, azure-application-insights, azure-diagnostics

I was following [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-cloudservices/) so I could add Diagnostics to my worker role. I followed all the steps but when I get up to Step 1 of the "Azure Diagnostics" section, I can see the "Send Diagnostics data to Application Insights" checkbox there, but I am unable to select it.

[image]

When I click on it, it doesn't toggle, stays unchecked.

What may cause this to occur? Are there any steps specific to Worker Roles to get this working that Web Roles didn't need?

Comment: Someone from the team is taking a look at this, will update here with a solution/workaround if any :) 
Dimah, Application Insights team.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.247200.00 Update 1 if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that I needed to put the instrumentation key in both the Cloud and Local service configurations. I had only had it on cloud as I thought I would only be using the diagnostics on cloud deployments.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't see the "Send diagnostics data to Application Insights" **dialog** when you click the Checkbox (which sounds like a bug, I'm wondering if this is happening to all of your worker role projects even with newly created ones), you can still manually edit the configuration files to achieve the same thing.

1. First go to the **Settings** tab in the role properties page and add a new setting item named "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY". The "Type" of the setting should be "String". The "Value" of the setting should be the instrumentation key of your target Application Insights resource. You can find it on the Azure portal by selecting the resource and then go to its Settings -> Properties blade.
2. Then open the "diagnostics.wadcfgx" file under your worker role in Solution Explorer. From there add an attribute "sinks" with value "applicationInsights.errors" to the "DiagnosticsMonitorConfiguration" element. The element should then looks like this:

   ```
   <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096" sinks="applicationInsights.errors">
   ```
3. In the same file, add the following section under the WadCfg element:

   ```
   <SinksConfig>
       <Sink name="applicationInsights">
         <ApplicationInsights />
         <Channels>
           <Channel logLevel="Error" name="errors" />
         </Channels>
       </Sink>
   </SinksConfig>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I get back to work on Monday and will reply if it works.

Comment: I have answered the question with the cause of the error and the resolution. Thanks for the assistance though.